# Component not reloaded with react hot loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-hot-loader

https://github.com/James2516/hot-reload

I'm trying to add [hot loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) to an existing webpack project.

[image]

It detected file changes but did not reload the component.

To reproduce:

1. `yarn && yarn start`
2. change `src/App.js` content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples are taken from https://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/#step-2-of-3-using-hmr-to-replace-the-root-component, though it seems as though you already followed this guide.

The first problem is that `[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...` is printed to the console twice, and any attempted recompiles also occur twice. This is caused by your `entry` in `./config/webpack/Dev.js` being:

```
entry: [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4545/',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  './client.js',
]
```

The first few steps of the guide have the entry point as:

```
[
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:3000', // WebpackDevServer host and port
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', // 'only' prevents reload on syntax errors
  './scripts/index' // Your app's entry point
]
```

**Step 3a** under  **Step 3 (of 3): Adding React Hot Loader to preserve component state** instructs you to modify the `entry` of `webpack.config.js` to look like:

```
[
  'react-hot-loader/patch', // RHL patch
  './scripts/index' // Your app's entry point
]
```

`react-hot-loader` handles what these two entries were previously doing, so they can be replaced with `'react-hot-loader/patch'`.

So your new entry point should be:

```
[
  'react-hot-loader/patch',
  './client.js'
]
```

Next, **Step 3b** in the same section has a code snippet that looks like:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./containers/rootContainer.js', () => {
    const NextRootContainer = require('./containers/rootContainer').default;
    render(NextRootContainer);
  });
}
```

Changing your `module.hot` block to:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    const newApp = require('./App').default;
    render(newApp);
  }
}
```

Correctly reloads the component, so it doesn't make sense that following **Step 3c** breaks HMR.

> c. Webpack 2 has built-in support for ES2015 modules, and you won’t need to re-require your app root in module.hot.accept. The example above becomes:
>
> ```
> if (module.hot) {
>   module.hot.accept('./containers/rootContainer', () => { 
>    render(RootContainer) });
> }
> ```
>
> Note: To make this work, you’ll need to opt out of Babel transpiling ES2015 modules by changing the Babel ES2015 preset to be
>
> `"presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }]]`

Which you did correctly in `.babelrc`. The only problem is that in `./config/webpack/Base.js` you have:

```
loader: 'babel-loader',
query: {
  presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-2']
}
```

This causes `babel-loader` to use these presets instead of the ones defined in `.babelrc`. Removing `query` in this rule and changing `presets` in `.babelrc` to:

```
"presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }], "react", "stage-2"
```

Correctly enables HMR with your `module.hot` block as:

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => { render(App); });
}
```

Comment: Removing `query` in `babel-loader` fixed it, thanks! It's still recompiling twice though. I tried modifying the `entry` https://github.com/James2516/hot-reload/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L34-L37 but it did not seem to have any effect. If it's working for you locally, can you make a PR so that I can see all the changes? Thanks!

Comment: I checked the most recent commit, and it looks good to me. My local configuration is recompiling twice as well, but previous to removing the two additional entries it was recompiling four times. I should've specified in my answer that two instances of `webpack-dev-server` were running before and now there's only one. You should be all set.